# How to Parse Array of JSON Objects using Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Using **Axios** I'm trying to pass `JSON` data as `params` to the endpoint URL.

My `params`:

```
const annotations = {
    "key": "Book.pdf",
    "pages": [
      {
        "start": "12",
        "end": "20"
      },
      {
        "start": "35",
        "end": "40"
      }
    ]
}
```

My `async` function:

```
try {
    const result = await axios.get(endpoint, {
        params: annotations,
        paramsSerializer: params => parseParams(params),
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'withCredentials': true
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Function to parse the URL ([GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/604#issuecomment-420135579)):

```
const parseParams = (params) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(params);
  let options = '';

  keys.forEach((key) => {
    const isParamTypeObject = typeof params[key] === 'object';
    const isParamTypeArray = isParamTypeObject && (params[key].length >= 0);

    if (!isParamTypeObject) {
      options += `${key}=${params[key]}&`;
    }

    if (isParamTypeObject && isParamTypeArray) {      
      params[key].forEach((element) => {
        options += `${key}=${element}&`;
      });
    }
  });

  return options ? options.slice(0, -1) : options;
};
```

The problem is that results in `error 500`:

```
https://api.mysite.com/ConvertBook?key=Book.pdf&regions=[object%20Object]&regions=[object%20Object]
```

I can't find a solution on the web, so how can I parse Array of JSON Objects in Axios?

Comment: It would be best to send encoded JSON string as qs param, If that's an option.

Comment: @ITgoldman Hi, I need it for my Lambda function...anyway how can I send encoded JSON using Axios, could you share something?

Comment: `"www.example.com?param=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.Stringify( [{x: 3, y: 4}, {x:2; z: 5}]))` - as there is no way I know to convert that to querystring, let alone if it was nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use JSON.stringify on your params...

```
const parseParams = (params) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(params);
  let options = [];

  keys.forEach((key) => {
    options.push(`${key}=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params[key]))}`);
  });

  return options.join('&');
};
```

Comment: Thanks but... `"Message: Request failed with status code 404 -AxiosError code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"`. I don't understand, in console params are now correctly send, the header with bearer and token is ok, my Lambda function works correctly with that JSON, so why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Url parsed: `https://api.mysite.com/ConvertBook?key=%22Book.pdf%22&regions=[{%22start%22:0,%22end%22:18},{%22start%22:5,%22end%22:14}]`

Comment: I've added encodeURIComponent to the function... Wasn't sure if that was needed by Axios.