# AWS HTTP API Gateway: how to parse Array of JSON Objects as query string for Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I made a connection between my `AWS HTTP API Gateway` and my `Lambda` Function (`ConvertBook`).

I test my function with this `JSON`:

```
{
    "key": "Book.pdf",
    "pages": [
      {
        "start": "12",
        "end": "20"
      },
      {
        "start": "35",
        "end": "40"
      }
    ]
}
```

My `Lambda` function is a simple `Python` script like:

```
if 'queryStringParameters' in event and 'pages' in event['queryStringParameters']:
    pages = event['queryStringParameters']['pages']
        
for element in pages:
    print(element['start'],' - ',element['end'])
```

Everything works great with `Lambda` however I'm not able to find the right way to parse the `URL` to be used in `API Gateway` to call it.

I tried different solutions, basically when I call this `URL`:

```
https://api.mysite.com/ConvertBook?key="Book.pdf"&pages=[{"start":"12","end":"20"},{"start":"35","end":"40"}]
```

I run into `"Internal Server Error"` message from `Lambda`.

So I would like to know, what is wrong with `AWS API Gateway` in this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the response from `AWS Support`:

> I observed that the querystring parameters are taken as key-values in
> string format. So, in order to access the parameters of the array, you
> have to parse the value of the "pages" parameter to list format
> using "json.loads" method

So, my solution was pretty easy:

```
import json

qsp = event['queryStringParameters']

if 'queryStringParameters' in event and 'pages' in qsp:
    pages = json.loads(qsp['pages'])
        
for element in pages:
    print(element['start'],' - ',element['end'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the test function of the AWS Lambda console with your JSON it isn't sending the same JSON as you would receive from API Gateway.

API Gateway will send a JSON payload with all the relevant information you might need about an HTTP request. In your case, you'll want to get data from the query string.

My advice would be to print out the entire API Gateway payload to see what the structure is like. You'll also find samples on the [Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html).

Comment: I already tried to send a JSON payload using Axios as you can see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72826788/how-to-parse-array-of-json-objects-using-axios). However it doesn't work, so I would like to understand what kind of syntax should I use

Comment: my only problem is the "pages" array, because it's an array of JSON objects, and I cannot find an example on how to use a get request to API Gateway in this scenario.

Comment: HI @NineCattoRules, if the problem is just passing a JSON structure to a query parameter on a GET endpoint, then I can see from your example that the string is not fully UrlEncoded. That is, JSON.stringify is not enough, you need to encodeURIComponent too (e.g. there should be no " left, those should be %22)

Comment: Hi Mark, it doesn't work either, this is the answer I received https://stackoverflow.com/a/72827003/4458531 As you can see it's already encodeURIComponent but from console I get Internal server error and the URL is same as here above